# Least square minimization of a Cost function

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, mathematical-optimization, least-squares, gradient-descent

I am aiming to minimize the below cost function over W

```
J = (E)^2
E = A - W .* B
Such that W(n+1) = W(n) - (u/2) * delJ

delJ = gradient of J = -2 * E .* B
u = step_size=0.2

where:
- A, B are STFT matrix of 2 audio signals (dimension is 257x4000 for a 16s audio with window size = 256 , 75% overlap, nfft=512)
- W is a matrix constructed with [257x1] vector repeated 4000 times (so that it become 257x4000] matrix
```

I have written my customize function as below. The problem is, the elements in A and B are so small (~e-20) <del>that even after 1000 iteration</del> that no change happens to g.

I am certainly missing something, if anybody can help or guide me to some link which explains the whole process for a new person.

```
[M,N] = size(A);

E =@(x) A - repmat(x,1,N) .* B; % Error Function
J = @(x) E(x) .^ 2; % Cost Function
G = @(x) -2 * E(x) .* B; % Gradiant Function

alpha = .2; % Step size
maxiter = 500; % Max iteration
dwmin = 1e-6; % Min change in gradiation
tolerence = 1e-6; % Max Gradiant norm

gnorm = inf;
w = rand(M,1);
dw = inf;

for i = 1:maxiter
    g = G(w);
    gnorm = norm(g);
    wnew = w - (alpha/2)*g(:,1);

    dw = norm(wnew-w)
    if or(dw < dwmin, gnorm < tolerence)
        break
    end
end
w = wnew;
```

A & B are always positive real numbered vectors.

Comment: There are several strange things here. First, your code runs only for one iteration, so you haven't given us the code that doesn't stop even after 1000 iterations. Second, your gradient function should return a vector the same size as `w`, but it is a matrix the same size as `A` and `B`. Then you only take the first column of that, so that it only depends on the first column of `A` and `B`, so effectively you are only solving the problem for that column.

Comment: Third (though irrelevant for your code), your cost function also has the size of the full matrix, where it should be a scalar. I think you should define it as `J = @(x) sum(sum(E(x) .^ 2));`

Comment: I tried to solve your problem (using the correct cost function) using a gradient-free method, `fminsearch`, and didn't get a solution either. Are you sure your problem *has* a unique solution? How did you come up with it? A little background might help to find a better approach.

Comment: HI, extremely sorry for the first issue. Actually i edited the code to add if() condition at the end [which now causes to break the loop after 1 iteration), but forgot to edit the line in text.

Comment: Actually, I am not sure whether it has a unique solution. Like I said, A and B here is actually 2 matrices derived from STFT of 2 audio signals. The objective of function E is to multiply each column of B(k,l) by a vector w(k) and then subtract from A(k,l). In this approach, the cost function J is not used anywhere, rather the gradient of J is important. If you want to use fminsearch, the scaler should be norm(J) I guess. However, with fminsearch, I don't think it is feasible to minimize over a vector of around 250 elements (i tried actually)

Comment: Ok, but what is the meaning of `w`?

Comment: it's frequency dependent weight. So, for all B(k,:), I have to multiply by W(k), k=1,2......256 (for a 256 point DFT)

Comment: So are you trying to find some sort of optimal filter?

Comment: Yes, sort of ....  I want to filter B so that norm of (A - filtered_B) is minimum

Comment: Ok, I'll think about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is actually a series of independent problems. If we index each row of `A` and `B` and each element of `w` with `i`, then minimizing the sum of squares across the error matrix

```
A - repmat(w, 1, N) .* B
```

is the same as minimizing the the sum of squares across the error vector

```
A(i, :) - w(i) * B(i, :)
```

for all rows separately. The latter problem can be solved using one of the least-squares operators of Matlab, in particular [`mrdivide`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html) or `/`:

```
for i = 1 : M
    w(i) = A(i, :) / B(i, :);
end
```

As far as I can tell, there is no way to further vectorize this calculation.

In any case, there is no need to use a gradient descent or other form of optimization algorithm.

Comment: Thanks, that's some interesting point. However, if I am not wrong, mrdivide will solve for Aw=B or Aw-B = 0 (=J) ... But but I need to minimize J^2, not J = 0. (just trying to understand the whole thing)

Comment: I forgot to mention, A & B are always positive real numbered vectors, if that has any significance.

Comment: @AbdFahim, yes, it solves for that in the least-squares sense, and that's exactly what you want. J = 0 would make J^2 = 0, too, which is the minimum conceivable value. If that can't be achieved, it gets as close to that as possible.